# ERROR: Root device mounted successfully, but /sbin/init does not exists

Tags: linux, установка, archlinux

Первый раз ставил **Arch Linux**, слава богу что на *VirtualBox*, при перезагрузке выскакивает такая ошибка:

```
ERROR: Root device mounted successfully, but /sbin/e4rat-preload does not exist.
Bailing out, you are on your own. Good luck.

sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
[rootfs /]#
```

С *Linux* знаком немного, сидел на *Debian* около полгода, решил попробовать *Arch*
Может знаете что делать? Или нужно заново ставить?
Спасибо!

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, `/sbin/init` или `/sbin/e4rat-preload`? Что у вас забыл e4rat?

Comment: Я не понимаю о чем вы, я просто ставил Arch linux по видео, можете указать мне что делать?

Comment: Не смотреть какие-то мутные видео от каких-то ноунеймов, а открывать [официальную документацию](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) и ставить по ней